# DataTables: #example working but #datatable not working when making AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I want to know the difference between #example and #datatable. I have seen one example there they are using one table with div id as *datatable* using some hardcoded value. And another table with div id as *example* . I can make a Ajax call for that second example. But i cant do it for first one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Json/CustomerListJson.php",
            "sScrollX": "70%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        } );
    } );                
</script>
```

The above code is working well.
But If i change the table id to datatable like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Json/CustomerListJson.php",
            "sScrollX": "70%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true
        } );
    } );                
</script>
<div id="dynamic">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display dataTable" id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>     
</div>
```

I got one warning pop alert which says

DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy.

This is my first project using Bootstrap CSS.
Please provide me the best way.

I want this type of look and feel.

[image]
But I got this type of table.
[image]

Finally I got this error message, if i use #datatable

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy
```

Comment: I refer this link for the second example http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html . But I dont want that look and feel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a warning when you initialize same datatable twice. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tNXnB/1/) example. Using an example given in the datatable [docs](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap) i was able to apply Bootstrap css. Check the same fiddle link.

If for some reason you are not able to remove the second datatable call, set bDestroy to true link this [example](http://live.datatables.net/#javascript,html) or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759303/jquery-datatable-redraw-issue) link `$("#tableId").dataTable().fnDestroy();`.

```
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false
    });

    // Some time later....
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bDestroy": true //<-- set bDestroy to true which will destroy the previous initializarion
    });
```

Change this

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Json/CustomerListJson.php",
        "sScrollX": "70%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true
    } );
```

to

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Json/CustomerListJson.php",
        "sScrollX": "70%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true
    } );
```

Comment: If I give <table id=example>, table will display just like 2nd Image.

Comment: At the same time if i use <table id=datatable> , table wont display and says DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: We have brought one Bootstrap template, there their datatable looks like first image.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can create a fiddle out of it :)

Comment: So if you add `<table id=datatable>` it gives a alert right. That means you have another call to `<table id=datatable>` in your js file.

Comment: As i said above in the code, try adding `"bDestroy": true` to your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18394/discussion-between-sridhar-and-bhb)

Comment: **This is the correct answer for applying Twitter Bootstrap to an existing dataTable** the only _additional_ steps to successfully styling dataTables with Bootstrap is to apply the Bootstrap table CSS classes  (I used $('table.dataTable').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered'); )  and to incorporate the CSS and JS files from [this article](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2)